# How to preprocess a special trigger in Rivescript-Python?

Tags: rivescript

My bot stores the name of the user in a database, and, from time to time, the database sends the session a message “setname username”. Sample rivescript:

```
+ setname *
- <set name=<formal>>

+ (what is my name|who am i)
- You're <get name>, right?

+ didntlike
- {topic=nlike}Why?

> topic nlike

+ *
- {topic=random}Thanks for charing.

< topic

+ *
- I don't have a reply for that.
- Try asking that a different way.
```

The problem is when the user is in a topic like ‘nlike’ that is exited by * and I send the message to set the name, then the conversation exits the topic.

Expected conversation:

```
Me: hello
Bot: I don't have a reply for that.
Me: didntlike
Bot: Why?
Me: setname John
Bot:
Me: I didn't like because you are ugly.
Bot: Thanks for charing.
Me: Who am I?
Bot: You're John, right?
```

Is there a way to treat that in the begin block? I tried different syntaxes, but no positive result. I thought of something like:

```
> begin

+ setname *
- <set name=<formal>>

+ request
- {ok}

< begin
```

One workaround is to add the same trigger inside all topics, but I need a better solution, because that approach is error prone as my rive files get bigger.

==== Code tried based on Nelson's answer =====

```
> begin
    + request
    - {ok}{topic=specialtriggers}
< begin

> topic specialtriggers

+ setname *
- <set name=<formal>>

< topic

+ (what is my name|who am i)
- You're <get name>, right?

+ didntlike
- {topic=nlike}Why?

> topic nlike

+ *
- {topic=random}Thanks for charing.

< topic

+ *
- I don't have a reply for that.
- Try asking that a different way.
```

I think adding the topic to {ok}{topic=specialtriggers} making all triggers outside this topic fail. After the preprocessing, Rivescript should answer if it is a specialtrigger or else search for the normal triggers.

Comment: I don't understand what do you expect the conversation go. Can you give some example sentences to make the point more concrete? Do you wish to enter the message `setname *` with star as a valid character not a trigger?

Comment: Yes. I expect to use the begin block to preprocess this message. Whenever I say 'setname John', I will set the variable 'name' to 'John'. This is useful because I don't have to replicate the trigger 'setname *' in every topic of my .rive files. I could also say something simpler like: 'close' and it responds by not entering the rive rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on [Noah Petherbridge's response](https://www.chatbots.org/ai_zone/viewthread/3264/) on [chatbots.org](https://chatbots.org), one viable solution is using topic inheritance:

```
> topic specialtriggers
    + setname *{weight=9991234}
    - <set name=<star1>>
< topic

> topic random includes specialtriggers
    // you don't actually need to put anything inside here, since triggers
    // without a topic are in the "random" topic automatically, but this
    // topic declaration line will make "random" include "important"
< topic

// but for your other topics, include the specialtriggers one
> topic nlike includes specialtriggers
    + *
    - {topic=random}Thanks for caring.
< topic
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is only about how to always preprocess user message using `begin` block, the answer is:

- Don't need to enter trigger into the begin block. A `+ request` is generic representation of any user message.
- If you would like to limit the triggers to be matched in begin block **only** from current topic, an `{ok}` tag is sufficient.

Modify your code as follow

```
+ didntlike
- {topic=nlike}Why?

> topic nlike
    + *
    - Thanks for charing.
< topic

> begin
    + request
    - {ok} (Preprocessed in begin)
< begin
```

Try the following sequence of message `didntlike`, `hello`, and you will see the replies are appended with `(Preprocessed in begin)`.

- Otherwise, reply in begin block need to add a topic where (which topic) to fetch the triggers and replies from. If you would like to fetch the trigger for `setname` in `random` topic, you can add the begin block into the end of your first code snippet.

The RiveScript code

```
> begin
    + request
    - {ok}{topic=random}
< begin
```

In this case, the topic after serving the request to `setname` is topic `random`.

Comment: Hello @nelson-dinh, thanks for your kind response but it didn't work. I think I didn't make myself clear so I added an expected result of conversation in my question and also added the code tried using your answer.